# IIS 7.5 Globe with Question Mark Icon

Tags: iis-7.5, network-protocols

I changed the Physical Path to my website in IIS 7.5 and the icon changed to this:

[image]

It was completely vanilla before I changed that. I can't find any documentation on what that icon means and the tooltip only says "Default Web Site (Multiple Protocols)" which can't be true because http is my only enabled protocol in advanced settings.

Here are my bindings:

[image]

Anyone know what that blasted icon means, and how to address this issue? OR, is this even something I need to be concerned about? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct answer was staring me right in the face, though I didn't know it at the time. Apparently this little "question mark" notation on the icon is simply to alert the site admin to the fact that these bindings exist.

As it turns out, you can have multiple bindings of the same protocol (say to different host aliases) and the icon will be just a globe, but when you add additional protocols to the same site, THEN you get the question mark. :)

Comment: So there's nothing to worry about then, and just leave it?

Comment: @Matthew Baker From a security and server hardening perspective, you should disable protocols which are not necessary for a given site in order to reduce the attack surface.

Comment: In that case I shall remove them at once.

Comment: In cleartext you can have http and https without the question mark, but bindings like net.tcp etc do cause the question mark. In my case, removing net.tcp etc also removed the question mark.

Answer (score 5):

Have you also enabled FTP on the same site? If so, then this is a known bug and can safely be ignored.

Comment: Please observe the above screenshot. Clearly ftp is not enabled. Please stop answering my questions with so little effort; it's beginning to feel like you're trolling me. :(

Comment: @Chiramisu I'm really not sure why you feel like you're being trolled. Feel free to downvote any answer that you feel is not useful.

Comment: Although not applicable to the original question, this answer is correct in case a website also publishes FTP. This is confirmed by the following article: [Installing and Configuring FTP 7 on IIS 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7), which states _The icon of a combined Web/FTP site may be marked with a question mark even though the site is currently started with **no error**. This occurs when a site has a mixture of HTTP/FTP bindings._. This issue is still present in IIS 8

Answer (score 0):

I think this extra binding is generated by MS SQL server installation.